# On The Sustainable Use of Metal Transmutation

Tags: society, humans, economy

In my story, it is possible (through alchemy, or some kind of mysterious magical process) to turn base metals into gold. This ability is not widespread, and knowledge of it is uncommon. In fact, most people and even most nations may be unaware of its existence. The Central Bank of a certain country has access to this ability, and uses it to maintain their country on the gold standard. However, they are aware of at least basic economic principles, and know that flooding the market with gold will quickly devalue it. What steps should this organisation take to ensure that their ability to cheaply generate gold continues to be useful? What risks would this generate, and what kind of cultures and/or institutions would need to be put in place to deal with those risks?

(Edit: For context, my idea is that the civilisation is placed roughly in the late 17-th early 18th century analogue. Reasonably advanced forms of government and warfare exist, but communication is fairly slow and analogue.)

Comment: "*some kind of mysterious **chemical** process*"  No.  Absolutely not.

Comment: I think you need to add more about the time period involved: ancient tribes or modern global economy?  What is the economic system of the region?

Comment: What is the time period for this?

Comment: edited to add details about time period.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

I should think this is not dissimilar to the real life situation of Norway (and a few others) with North Sea Oil. That is also a form of "free money", if you will; trillions of dollars worth of something they can get for relatively low mining costs.

Shouldn't your situation be similar? Have the government nationalize a large area of what is otherwise wasteland (say desert like New Mexico or Arizona), and "discover" gold there, a hundred feet down! But of course they just made a show of digging a great big hole, at the bottom of which they convert base metals into gold. They keep digging, but as a social service they hire the least intelligent citizens to work there, telling them the gold is in microscopic form and must be refined out, but every rock is chock full of it! That's why they only see rock and dirt. But they are making a good living and helping their country, they are heroes!

Your government can follow Norway's model: Their oil (your gold) is converted to cash; after paying their own citizens to work the oil rigs (your gold mine) the rest of the cash goes into a national fund; this fund invests the money in all sorts of ventures (tens of thousands of them). They earn about 10% to 15% on the money; and by Norwegian law, only the **profits** are allowed to be used to fund their government, their welfare programs, etc. The capital is never touched (well it can be diminished by failed ventures; but the Norwegian government is not allowed to use it or borrow against it for expenses).

Here is why that is important, and how it balances your gold production: Your gold will only ever fund legitimate business enterprises that have to gain a market in order to make a profit. Think of such business enterprises as more or less *inevitable.* People are going to invent things, or services, or whatever, and sell them, with or without your help. But (if your gold is not in the picture) the profits all these ventures earn get distributed widely, to many millions of investors. On **average** they all make that 10% to 15%. The market is never crashed by this profit making; all the profit comes from people that were willing to part with their money for whatever they bought; it is a legitimate creation of new value through human creativity and labor.

But with your gold **in the picture**, you are just outbidding thousands of those investors with an extra 5% or 10% to the entrepreneurs, and **you** take the profit those investors otherwise would have had. You just edge them into funding the riskier investments and taking more losses, and the entrepreneurs you are funding get a little extra equity or 10% more money to make their ideas work.

In business terms, you make the pie smaller so you can take a bigger piece of it: by giving the entrepreneurs a more generous deal you reduce the total amount of profit available to investors, but your little country is getting far more than its fair share.

This won't crash the economy, because your magic is really just diverting profits that **would have been earned anyway** into your pocket instead of the pockets of other investors. It is just a **redistribution** of the profits.

Your cost is the sham of pretending what you are mining is 20% gold, when you are crushing worthless rock and turning scrap iron into gold. But of course you have insanely high security around the mine, inside the mine, and where the transmutation actually occurs: Only the wizards in the hardhats are ever allowed to empty the final centrifuges and crucibles of the "final product".

Or something like that; I am sure there must be ways to mix pure transmuted gold into the crushed rock so you can "burn off" the rock and "purify" the residue into tons of gold, so to outside observers it has all the appearance of a real operating mine.

By analogy, suppose Norway had discovered a magical way of converting sea water into crude oil, and decided to *pretend* they were drilling for it, to the point of actually drilling holes and arranging for transmuted sea water to look like it was coming up from those holes. I'm not sure we'd know (or care) what was *really* happening half a mile beneath the North Sea.

Comment: One significant difference between oil and gold is that oil gets *consumed*. So Norway is participating in an open system where oil both enters and exits, and they can adjust their production to maintain equilibrium (and if they overproduce, they can correct that), whereas this hypothetical kingdom produces gold that sticks around forever. There's no steady-state equilibrium, no correcting for overproduction.

Comment: @ruakh That is immaterial; any gold mine is doing the same. What if Norway found half a trillion dollars worth of Gold in the North Sea, and sold it for half a trillion dollars? There is no difference, Gold is **also** consumed by people buying it and holding it. It isn't money, and its value is not due to rarity: Ruthenium is more rare, harder to mine, and sells for about 5% the price of gold. Gold's value is in the minds of those that want to own it --- end of story. That is why it fluctuates so wildly in price; its value is a **cultural** phenomenon; not intrinsic in any way.

Comment: also, gold is very much consumed in standard sense, it is heavily used in all kinds of industries. That might have been different in OP's time period tho. Props to anyone who can come up with was of consuming gold in victorian era to keep gold overproduction in check

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have a money that are worthless in their own now, having any worth only because people believe it. And your central bank can print, wait, transmute more on a whim but people trust it not to. Congratulations, your people basically introduced [fiat money](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money), not by decoupling existing money from gold backing, but by turning the very gold to something without value. Doesn't matter, it's all the same.

1. Your central bank has power of central bank against other countries that still use gold.
2. You can introduce and regulate inflation, to prevent hoarding, to make sure your economy wouldn't be coin-thirsty etc
3. If you are slow enough for other countries to keep using gold, inflation in your country will mean that their goods will be getting cheaper. Good for import, bad for export.
4. Being too open about that prematurely, or being greedy, will make other countries turn to other metals for coins, and may end up with hyperinflation.

Responsibility of institutions able to print money is a complicated matter, a field of study too broad to fully describe, so keep in mind that's exactly what you did, and keep above points in mind.

Comment: Sorry, but you've misunderstood commodity/fiat money. Commodity money (such as gold) is considered valuable due to the material without consideration of form. Transmuted gold is indistinguishable from natural gold, and so has the same value. With that said, yes, transmutation can easily produce inflation or hyperinflation, just as, for instance, American gold inflated the Spanish economy in the 1500's.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast nope. Transmuted gold and natural gold in this world are both valuable only because people believe it. No intristic value anymore, if you can have as much of it as you want, whenever you want. Only not everyone realizes that, yet. Same as with banknotes.

Comment: Sigh. No. Just no  Any substance, including gold, is only valuable if people think it is. Now, it's true that gold has had some nice features - it's rare, pretty, and durable, and any trophy wife or rich man's mistress can tell you about the value of that combination. But while a gold piece is intrinsically valuable (due to its gold content) gold as a substance is not intrinsically (in the sense of universally or objectively)  valuable, and has not been universally used as a medium of exchange. See, for instance, the Aztec culture.

Comment: @molot: (Sorry WhatRoughBeast) The value of money is in the minds of people, it is valuable because people believe they can trade it for stuff, like services, food, shelter. To the extent the people are correct, the monetary unit has value. It is not rarity; ruthenium is more rare than gold and harder to mine; but is worth $65 vs $1265 per troy ounce. Gold has no value without faith others want it; and in a post apocalyptic starving society, I won't sell a pound of food for any amount of gold because nobody else would either! If they do, they die. There is no intrinsic value in anything.

Comment: @Amadeus so you're arguing that gold is effectively a Fiat currency now?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast nope. You are missing distinction between fiat currency, worth only because people believe it to be worth, and commodity currency. For example food is always worth about one day of not being hungry per 2 - 5 meals. But with money made of tin (or of gold made of tin), face value is much higher than commodity value, and that's fiat money.

Comment: @k_g I'd argue it was never anything else, nor is any form of money. It only has value, and you will only take it in trade, if you are very confident you can trade it back for something else. Rarity is not value, rarity is meaningless. A 20 dollar bill has value because I am certain it will be taken in trade by virtually everyone in the USA. Gold likewise, but if the day comes when you can't find anyone to take your bills or gold coins in exchange for their food, medicine or gunpowder, then **those** things become the medium of exchange. The value is in the faith of a future utility for trade.

Comment: @Amadeus so if a culture were to use something frequently consumed as currency (e.g. crude oil) and continued to consume it, it would be an exception?

Comment: @k_g Exception to what, exactly? Prison culture uses cigarettes, frequently consumed, as currency. Many cultures use food (corn, beans, jerky) and food animals (sheep, cattle, goats) as currency, and consume them. Even salt has been used as currency; it was both consumed and traded (used as pay for labor). This is not just barter: anything I trust can be *easily* traded (within my culture) for most things I want is a currency, whether it is a consumable or not.

Comment: So what I'm saying is that these kinds of "barter"-style exchanges are an exception to money only having value if others believe it has value. They are intrinsically valuable at the market price. If everyone started using something else as currency, you could still sell them.

Answer (score 1):

It has actually happened; and, sadly, it didn't work.

There are three fundamental problems with the premise: first, *nobody* in the late 17th century had any idea of *"basic economic principles"* — Adam Smith's seminal *[Wealth of Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wealth_of_Nations)* was published in 1776, that is, in the second half of the 18th century; second, gold was always too expensive to be used in everyday transactions — at all times and in all places the metal in actual circulation was silver; and third, money is just a lubricant, not a fuel: it makes economic transactions easier, it accelerates exchanges, but it does not, in itself, produce national wealth.

(That's to avoid the obvious observation that in the late 17th or early 18th century there was no such thing as a central bank. There wasn't even the faintest idea of a central bank. What would a central bank even *do* in the 17th century?)

Leaving aside the mechanism proposed in the question, there actually was a powerful nation which, at one time, found a means to produce unlimited amounts of precious metals: that was Spain, which in the 15th and 16th century conquered a huge empire in the New World and gained access to gold and silver deposits beyond all imagination. *[The Spanish Treasure Fleets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1561642614)* (link goes to Amazon) brought so much gold and silver into Europe that "[prices rose sixfold over 150 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation)" (Wikipedia), generating the [price revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_revolution) which was one of the most important factors in the final demise of the medieval world.

Because the value of one monetary unit is not given by some mysterious intrinsic property of the material of which it is made; the value of one monetary unit is simply the value of the goods and services available for sale divided by the number of monetary units in circulation. A small and steady increase in the number of available monetary units *may* be conducive to a stable economic growth, provided the economy has the capacity to increase productivity to match. Today, central banks routinely [target an inflation rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_targeting) of about 2 or 2½ per cent per year, which is adequate for a modern reasonably developed economy; but in the 17th or 18th century economies were must less sophisticated than today. (And while modern central banks can easily provide limitless amounts of money, no transmutation needed, they still miss their inflation target at least as often as they hit it.)

So basically what the fortunate king or prince or emperor can do is to put a small amount of the newly found metal in circulation, not as a gift, but as a price paid for actual goods and services — essentially start a public works program. (This is the fundamental principle of the [Keynesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynesian_economics) recipe for bootstrapping an economy out of a recession.) They should take care that prices don't run away, and they should try to avoid using the new metal to pay for unessential imports. (Spain did not heed this advice, and used her immense treasure to pay for everything and anything, thus destroying her own competitivity and eventually losing her empire and her power.) Once the economy grows sufficiently, expand the public works program a little bit, but never overdo it lest the artisans and the farmers and the bankers and the industrialists become addicted to state contracts.

Using monetary policy is tricky, and there is still no sure-fire guaranteed recipe. That a 17th century ruler could get it right is possible, but bordering on the miraculous: that is, a great subject for an engaging story.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make just enough gold as is necessary for a healthy, growing economy, and
2. make up a reasonable cover story as to where it's getting it.  (EDIT: for example, plant the gold in a "rich, but narrow vein", and then make sure that the "miners" are loyal, and not too plentiful.)